# Executing a command in all running emacs instances

Tags: unix, emacs

I have two VNC sessions where I access same projects.
I have multiple emacs sessions open for multiple projects.
After saving my work on VNC1 and when using VNC2, I would need a way to run a command "update all opened files" in each emacs that is running on VNC2 so it sync up with changes happened in VNC1.

I have tied up F10 to do "revert-all-buffers" so I would need this script to go in each emacs and does the update.
So instead of me going to each opened emacs and pressing "F10" I want the script to do so.

Any pointers on how to approach this?

Comment: As an alternative, you could try running one Emacs session, and use new frames for each project. Then your `revert-all-buffers` would apply to every project.

Comment: Each project is big enough to have it's own emacs session. I also use shortcuts to build/Mercurial diffs based on the project the file resides in, I don't want to pollute log buffers with many info from different projects.

Comment: What does it mean that a project is "big enough to have it's own emacs session"? That sentence doesn't make sense to me. You also mention projects. Are you using any of the project libraries available for Emacs?

Comment: Chris, forget about the reasons I am running multiple emacs sessions. Assume it is any other program that I need to execute a command inside it's different instances on a unix box. I am looking for a script to do that.

Comment: "Assume it is any other program that I need to execute a command inside it's different instances on a unix box. I am looking for a script to do that." You're asking how to reach inside a running application and perform some tasks inside it. There is no general solution for this; you'll have to do *something* application-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this chunk of code and customize the `'synchronize-on-this` function to do whatever you want (right now it just prints a message).

```
(defvar synchronize-file "~/.synchronize" )
(defun synchronize-on-this ()
  (when (string-equal (file-truename synchronize-file) 
                     (file-truename (buffer-file-name)))
    (message "Have synchronized!")))

(find-file-noselect synchronize-file)
(global-auto-revert-mode 1)

(add-hook 'after-revert-hook 'synchronize-on-this)
```

Just make your <kbd>F10</kbd> bind to a function that writes to the `synchronize-file` and you're good to go.  You could store information in that file that's used during synchronization - or not.

Comment: Very interesting, but so I can understand, how this exactly works?
Assuming I already have 4 emacs sessions 2 in each VNC, all accessing the same files. Moving from VNC1 to VNC2 does this code detect automatically that something has changed and syncup? Remember, I wont be opening a new emacs sessions in the second VNC, all emacs applications are already open and stay open.

Comment: Your question made it sound like you want some command to execute in each Emacs instance at a particular time.

If all you really want is for all the buffers to revert, just use `(global-auto-revert-mode 1)`...  But if you need to actually do something substantive in each of the projects (e.g. check files out), you can do that in place of the `(message "Have synchronized!")`.

Comment: Trey, bare with me for a second. So if I have two emacs sessions opening the same file, I changed the file in one, if I switch to the second emacs would the file be already updated with the change automatically?

Comment: Yup - `global-auto-revert-mode` does just that.  It may take a few seconds, but it'll happen.  And, even without the mode enabled, if you ever try to edit a file in a 2nd Emacs, it'll check to see if it's changed on disk and warn you.